# java.util package - classes vs interfaces

Tags: java, interface, stack, queue

Why is [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) an interface, but others like [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) and [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) are classes?

I understand that interfaces are made so that clients can implement them and add on their own methods, whereas with classes if every client needs their methods in there it will become huge and bloated..

...or am I missing something here?

Comment: You've correctly spotted a mild inconsistency. Java is pretty good, overall, but alas out here in The World nothing is exactly right. :-)

Veer's answer below mentions that Stack is from an older version, but sometimes everything has to stick around.

Comment: It's interesting that if you click on "use" of the `Queue` API docs, you'll see implementations but nothing that actually uses it. In normal usage it's used privately within a class. There would be no significant impact if the interface did not exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `Queue` can be implemented in a number of fashions, as can a `List` or a `Set`. They all merely specify a contract for different kinds of collections.

An `ArrayList`, however, is a particular implementation of a `List`, made to internally use an array for storing elements. `LinkedList` is also an implementation of a `List`, which uses a series of interconnected nodes, i.e. a [doubly linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list). Similarly, `TreeSet` and `HashMap` are particular implementations of sets and maps, respectively.

Now, `Stack` is a odd case here, particularly because it is a legacy class from older versions of Java. You really shouldn't use a `Stack` anymore; instead, you should use its modern equivalent, the [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html). `ArrayDeque` is an implementation of a `Deque` (a double-ended queue), that internally uses an array for storage (which is just what `Stack` does). A `Deque` supports all of the operations of a `Stack`, like `pop`, `push`, etc. Other implementations of `Deque` include `LinkedList`, as mentioned by someone else, although this deviates from `Stack` in that underlying it is not an array,  but a doubly-linked list :-p

Now, there are plenty of implementations of `Queue`, and many different types of `Queue`s. You not only have `BlockingQueue`s (often used for producer-consumer), whose common implementations include `LinkedBlockingQueue` and `ArrayBlockingQueue`, but also `TransferQueue`s, and so on. I digress... you can read more on the collections API in the relevant [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apologies for the late thank you note. I remember reading this and it making sense but completely forgot to reply.

Answer (score 3):

You get the idea of interfaces correctly. In this case Java standard library already provides both implementations and interfaces. 
You are better of using an interface so you can switch the implementation any time.

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Stack` is well-renowned for being a class that should be an interface. The Java libraries are a bit hit-and-miss when it comes to correctly choosing to provide an interface.

`ArrayList` is just an implementation of the `List` interface, so Sun got it correct there! Another classic miss (in my opinion) is the `Observable` class, which very much needs to be the default implementation of an interface, rather than just a class.

Comment: `Observable` is very much a 1.0 class. A slightly more modern equivalent is `java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport`, which you'd have by composition.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. My thought about this that `Queue` is a basis for a lot of data structures like BlockingQueue, PriorityQueue, Deque, etc. This bunch of classes need specific implementation for various operations so it's much simpler to made `Queue` as interface.

Answer (score 0):

The reason interfaces are used for List and Queue is **NOT** to reduce excessive code.

The main advantage of interfaces is they allow you to write flexible, loosely coupled code.

(Here's an [awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) that describes this concept perfectly)

An interface simply defines a list of methods that will be implemented by a class.

This allows us to do a wonderfully powerful thing:

- *We can treat all classes that implement an interface the same.*

This is a HUGE advantage.

Here's a very simple example:

We want to write a debug method that prints every element in a [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).

[Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) is an interface.  It defines a list of operations and does not implement them.

You **cannot** instantiate a Collection.  You **can** instantiate a class that implements Collection.

There are many classes that implement [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html): ArrayList, Vector, TreeSet, LinkedList, etc...  They all have *different* snazzy features, but they *also* have certain things in common: Because each class *implements Collection*, they all implement each method [found here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#method_summary).

This allows us to do a very powerful thing:

- *We can write a method that operates on **ANY** class that implements Collection*.

It would look just like this:

```
public void printCollection(Collection semeCollection) {
    for (Object o : someCollection) {
       String s = (o == null) ? "null" : o.toString(); 
       System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Because of the magic of interfaces, we can now do the following:

```
public void testStuff() {

    Collection s = new TreeSet();
    Collection a = new ArrayList();
    Collection v = new Vector();

    s.add("I am a set");
    a.add("I am an array list");
    v.add("I am a vector");

    printCollection(s);
    printCollection(a);
    printCollection(v);
}
```